# Ionic2 running on browser hot to navigate away from app and back

Tags: angular, ionic2

I working in my oauth2 authentication in Ionic2. So far I´ve seen that you can use Cordova InAppBrowser plugin to accomplish the part where you navigate to the website and grant access to the App but cannot seem to find a way to t

Comment: My connection got interrupted and the post was published only halfway. I am not able to edit it either. Anyway, you can use inappbrowser plugin in a mobile device but cannot seem to find a way to do something similar in a web browser running on a PC. Anyone knows if this is doable?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins do not work when you do `ionic serve` on PC. They need a webview.

It is not possible to run it there.You could try an emulator.
If you want a browser,you can try

```
ionic platform add browser
```

and

```
ionic run browser
```

**This will add browser as a platform to your app**

Comment: Thanks Suraj, I will give it a try